# Verifying third party apps doesn't do anything

Tags: iphone, ios, third-party

When I get a third party app it says it needs to be verified before I can use it but when I go to settings to verify I tap verify and nothing happens. Is there something I can do so I don’t have to constantly reinstall my apps?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what this looks like on screen? Also - from where specifically are you getting apps? Xcode or side loading or jailbreak or an MDM push perhaps?

Comment: @bmike I reinstalled the apps so I had to upload a screenshot of another app I don’t use anymore but it shows the same thing. I use AppValley to get apps. I just downloaded it from safari.

Comment: That app is for downloading apps illegally. We're don't provide support for piracy.

Comment: @grgarside the app can be used to download apps illegally but I use it to download apps that can’t be downloaded any other way. All the apps I’ve gotten aren’t available in my regions App Store and I can’t change my App Store. And the app in the screenshot is one that I don’t use. I screenshotted that to show what happens to all my third party apps.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to run illegal copies of apps (or more precisely - enterprise signed apps when the membership of the enterprise isn't at all what Apple intended).

Tapping Verify like you do *is* the correct way to verify apps and will check / log information that Apple uses presumably to decide to contact that Enterprise if they are indeed in violation of their agreement with Apple.

If nothing happens, it's almost certainly due to Apple revoking the developer certificate because it's been used to distribute apps illegally or without a license or with a certificate issued for other purposes.

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense because the app I get the copies from doesn’t ask for verification and I’ve had it for a couple months but the apps I get from it only work for about a week and I have to reinstall because I can’t verify them.

Comment: @Actual The app in your screenshot is specifically for downloading apps illegally. I'm perfectly accurate here, Apple notice the certificate being used for sharing apps illegally and revoke the certificate. Therefore the certificate can't be verified and the apps can no longer be launched.

Comment: yes the app in the screenshot is meant for that but so is the current app that I have and I’ve never had to reinstall or verify the current app but I’ve had to reinstall/verify the apps I get from it. Which is actually a little confusing.

Comment: @Actual_donut No accusation or judgement on you but I'm guessing you are a customer of this "enterprise" and not an employee / partner of this enterprise. If so, they are bypassing the Apple App Store. Either way - reach out to their IT department and have them contact Apple to get their affairs / usage of signing certs in order again.

Comment: @bmike I’m not entirely sure who I would need to go to since the apps are from other developers. They aren’t produced or modified by the “enterprise”. They just distribute the apps and nowhere in the apps can I find any links or emails I can use to contact them.

Comment: @Actual_donut Go to the App Store and obtain the apps legally. Contact the developers of the apps and request they are made available in your country. Go to the site where you got the certificate and find a way to contact someone. That should cover paid, foreign, and (at your own discretion) third-party ways. The most important thing to understand when trying to do shady things is that when you come to a site for developers asking about something used to rob them of their income, you shouldn't expect your hand to be held.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are using apps that contains modified versions of App Store apps and free versions of paid AppStore apps, I am assuming that by you’re comments you are downloading apps from TweakBox, which uses a configuration profile so that it doesn’t expire